# Зачем в вёрстке используют так много div-ов?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, веб-дизайн

Коллеги, всем привет!) Я начинающий веб-разраб. Простите мою неловкость, друзья, но у меня очень новичковский вопрос: почему верстальщики в своей работе так любят заворачивать контент в большое количество div-ов? То есть допустим на страничке используется картинка - тег `<img/>` - и она завёрнута в 15 div-ов. Зачем? Просто если нужно выстроить какую-то иерархию стилей, не легче использовать классы, допустим?
Спасибо за ответ, друзья)

Comment: какой то эффект надо повторить или сделать ...

Comment: Мне кажется так делают бутстраперы, ну либо совсем неопытные.
Даже в больших проектах не так много вложенность, хотя всё зависит от задачи.. Личные наблюдения и имхо.

Comment: если к примеру img обернуть в 6 div - то img на самом деле будет обёрнут в 15 блоков/псевдо блоков и можно наделать кучу эффектов анимаций и прочего

Comment: Насчет 15ти не скажу, а вот `<div><img></div>` это классический паттерн разметки респонсивного изображения (в CSS по селектору вложенного img добавляется `max-width: 100%;`, и вуаля). Остальные слои div-оберток могут присутствовать по очень разным причинам... и далеко не все из этих возможных причин уважительные :) например, один тошнотный БЭМ чего стоит... А еще, есть всякие генераторы разметки / конструкторы - они вообще абсолютную дичь генерят.

Answer (score 1):

не всегда достаточно использовать один `<img>` или `<div><img></div>` многое зависит от дизайна и расположения в нем элементов, в следствии которого ты строишь структуру и на выходе, да у тебя полно div'ов, главное грамотно построить структуру, но большую вложенность не всегда удается избежать